# ¿Cual es tu opinión sobre sitios con contenido de Stack Overflow traducidos automáticamente al español?

Tags: discusión

A lot of thanks to [@Pikoh](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/15301/pikoh) for the translation!

---

#### La historia del problema

Hace un año, los desarrolladores de habla rusa se encontraron con un número creciente de sitios que contienen solo contenido traducido automáticamente de Stack Overflow en inglés. Cada mes un sitio así añade un millón de traducciones a su base de datos. Existen docenas de esos sitios. En este abril, esos lugares comenzaron a dominar los resultados de búsqueda en ruso para casi cualquier consulta. Las traducciones automáticas son en su mayoría de muy baja calidad, así que ni siquiera siempre es posible entender el significado de lo que está escrito ahí. Todo esto causa mucha frustración entre los desarrolladores de habla rusa.

#### ¿Cómo lidia la comunidad de habla rusa con este problema?

Tras varias solicitudes por parte la comunidad, creamos [una lista de sitios con traducciones automáticas](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7104/6). Bloqueamos publicaciones con enlaces a estos sitios en Stack Overflow en ruso (curiosamente,  una táctica similar se usa en la Wikipedia, donde [los enlaces externos a sus réplicas están prohibidos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Mirrors_and_forks)).

A muchos desarrolladores les disgustan tanto los sitios con traducción automática que han creado [extensiones para la redirección automática estos enlaces a Stack Overflow en inglés](https://github.com/Taraflex/Back2stackoverflow), para cuando accidentalmente pulsan en un enlace a uno de estos sitios con traducciones automáticas. Para ellos esta solución funciona, pero hay muchos otros que sufren este problema. En Stack Overflow en ruso comenzamos una [discusión](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8371/6) sobre qué puede hacer nuestra comunidad para solucionar esto. Creemos que entre todos podemos encontrar una buena solución al problema.

#### ¿Cómo se ve este problema en español?

Esto es lo que está pasando en la red rusa. ¿Podríais compartir vuestros pensamientos sobre que está pasando con estos contenidos traducidos automáticamente al español de Stack Overflow en inglés?

- ¿Te has encontrado tú o tus colegas con sitios con contenido traducido de Stack Overflow en inglés? Si es así, ¿cuál fue tu experiencia? (Si es posible, comparte enlaces a estos sitios en los comentarios de esta pregunta.)
- ¿Qué piensas de estos sitios con contenido traducidos automáticamente? ¿Te gustan o lo consideras un problema?
- Si piensas que es un problema, ¿qué tipo de soluciones sugerirías?

*¡Por favor, comparte tus opiniones sobre este tema!*

<sub>N. del T.: Dejo el texto original debajo por si alguien quiere mejorar la traducción.</sub>

---

#### The history of the problem

One year ago, Russian-speaking developers faced a rise of sites that contain only machine translated content from Stack Overflow in English. Each month one such site adds up to one million translations to its database. There are dozens of such sites. Around this spring, those sites began to dominate the search results in the Russian language for almost every search query. Machine translations on the sites are for the most part very low quality, so it is not always even possible to understand the meaning of what is written there. All this causes a lot of frustration among Russian-speaking developers.

#### How does the Russian-speaking community deal with the problem?

After several requests from the community, we created [a list of sites with machine translations](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7104/6). We block posts with links to these sites on Stack Overflow in Russian (interestingly, a similar approach is used on Wikipedia, where [external links to its replicas are prohibited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Mirrors_and_forks)).

Many developers dislike sites with machine translation so much that they have created [extensions for auto redirection to Stack Overflow in English](https://github.com/Taraflex/Back2stackoverflow), for cases when they accidentally hit a machine translation site. It works for them, but far more people suffer. On Stack Overflow in Russian we started a [discussion](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8371/6) about what our community can do to this problem. We believe that together we can find a good solution to the problem.

#### What does the problem look like in Spanish?

This is what’s happening in Ru-net. Could you please share your thoughts on what is happening with machine translated content from Stack Overflow in English in the Spanish language:

- Have you or your colleagues encountered sites with machine translated content from Stack Overflow in English? If so, what was your experience? (If possible, share links to such sites in the comments to this question.)
- How do you feel about sites with machine translated content? Do you like them or consider it a problem?
- If you think that it’s a problem, what kind of solutions would you suggest?

*Please share your thoughts on the topic!*

Comment: Please feel free to answer in the Spanish language. It's me who writes in the wrong language here (I'm apologise for that).

Comment: As @PabloLozano remarks in his answer, at the moment this does not seem to be an issue in Spanish. I know the existence of this sites, but never found a link to any of them in my search for information. Anyway, this situation could change in the future, so it's not a bad idea to think how to deal with this in case some day becomes a problem.

Comment: Since the content of the site is available through the API, is there anything that Stack Exchange can do legally against these sites?

Comment: @fedorqui I don't think so. All content in Stack Exchange is creative commons i believe (attribution required), so there's nothing Stack Exchange can do against those sites...

Comment: @fedorqui We want to keep the content as free as it could be and will not change the license. We believe in the people, in our community. I think together we will find a solution.

Comment: just a note.. your spring is my fall... since spanish is on the two sides of the world, consider using months when using timelines on spanish sites ;)

Comment: @gbianchi I did my best, could you please check my spelling? =)

Comment: you did great @NicolasChabanovsky... it's a minor problem.. (spring is september for you.. march for me ;) )

Answer (score 5):

Actually I became aware of their existence when looking for Q&A free software<sup>1</sup> but it seems their current Page Rank is very low so they are not present in the first 10 result pages when you search anything.

We have commented it in the SOes chat, but just as a curiosity: Translations are awful and mostly useless, so we (I think) did not give it any second thought.

<sup>1</sup> I noticed LibreOffice has its own [Q&A site](https://ask.libreoffice.org/), I was surprised that it was not part of SE like AskUbuntu

---

Descubrí la existencia de estos *clones* un día que me puse a curiosear sobre software de Q&A (preguntas y respuestas) libre, pero no aparecen en las búsquedas en Google en los primeros resultados, su Page Rank debe ser muy bajo (por suerte).

Las traducciones al español son muy malas y generalmente producen texto sin sentido, poco útil.

Lo comentamos en el chat de SOes, pero como una curiosidad sin mucha relevancia, era curioso encontrar respuestas nuestras de SO (en inglés) traducidas al español y ven cómo destrozaban el idioma :P.

Comment: Gracias por los comentarios! =) I'm really glad to hear that such sites have low PR in the Spanish language. Unfortunately, it's the opposite in Russian.

Comment: Then, as @pikoh comments, we should do something *just in case*.

Comment: If you have any ideas about what we can do about those sites, please, share them any time! It's a very interesting and important topic.

Answer (score 2):

### El problema:

EL problema es cuestión de un nicho de mercado particular y por lo tanto, un problema de marketing y no somos las personas más expertas en ello.
Agrego como comentario, que he hallado muchos blogs cuyos dueños viven de traducir SOen, simplemente usan las herramientas de marketing de **ogle y obtienen las mayores búsquedas para los problemas mas comúnes de cierto lenguaje o IDE, por ello sus traducciones son mejores que las automatizadas y muchas veces es gente que sabe acerca del tema lo suficiente para complementarlo (otras veces no).

### Como afrontarlo:

- legalmente: todo el contenido de SOen y SOes está legislado, así que se les puede solicitar que agreguen un enlace al sitio original.
- buscando un experto en marketing ( o tal vez inteligencia de negocios? )
- invirtiendo en la comunidad local ( a nadie le cae mal un dinosaurio o una nube voladora a cambio de amor incondicional )

### ¿Por qué prefiero yo a SOes sobre los clones?

En una palabra "relevancia".
Este es un sitio muy relevante para mí debido a que:

- las preguntas relacionadas son semanticamente relevantes gracias a la comunidad
- la calidad de la comunidad local, en las redes sociales de hispanohablantes abundan advenedizos con egos muy inflados, este es un sitio donde realmente he podido hallar mucha gente que sabe una enormidad de cosas ( un minuto de silencio por nuestro segundo moderador de comunidad que huyo de SOes decepcionado al parecer ), y en donde no me preocupa que la gente se pueda meter a mi vida personal.
- El esfuerzo de la comunidad en mejorar la calidad del contenido. Aquí hay mucho que decir, entendemos que muchos de los usuarios particulares de nuestra comunidad son tercermundistas, que no tienen la formación que quieren sino la que pueden. He hallado preguntas que no tenían la más mínima congruencia y que aún así les hemos podido entender y ajustar la pregunta para que fuera fácilmente hallada por otras personas.
- los wikis de comunidad: de verdad, gracias por preservarlos, son un conglomerado de conocimiento que nunca termina y que nos permiten corregir muchas carencias (que aquí son bastante comunes).
- Las encuestas, y especialmente sus resultados, son muy alentadores y atraen a mucha gente
- Que puedo preguntar en mi idioma y alguien me responde a la brevedad, muchos como yo no somos tan eficientes al comunicarnos con otras personas en la vida cotidiana, el comunicarme en el idioma que domino me permite expresarme de una manera más precisa y fluida.

En SOen:

- Amo que el soporte a muchas de las preguntas las den las mismas personas que hicieron las librerías (mayormente open source), si pregunto algo acerca de Dukescript tengo una alta probabilidad que el Java Champion que desarrolló el lenguaje me oriente personalmente, o que si pregunto de Bazel, alguien de ese equipo y que trabaja en Google me pueda orientar. Esto aún no existe notoriamente en nuestra comunidad, pero esperemos lograrlo pronto.
- La comunidad es bastante geek... así que uno se siente increíblemente normal
- Hay una cultura SOen, que se da muy natural, que se ha construido a lo largo del tiempo, una vez que empiezar a conocer todo lo relacionado con burninate no puedes para de leer artículos.
- La calidad de las preguntas es apabullante, yo me quedo mucho tiempo en el sitio aún después de hallar lo que busco debido a que las preguntas relacionadas son preguntas de problemas que ya enfrenté o que posiblemente enfrente inminentemente.
- diversidad, uno aprende mucho entrando a los perfiles de los demás, sé que este es un tema relevante, así que hablaré un poco más de esto, me es interesente saber que gente que nunca conoceré, que provienen de univeridades en las que nunca hubiera podido entrar y que trabajan en cosas que nunca lograré están contribuyendo a la misma comunidad, que trabajan en los mismos temas y que soy capaz de influenciarlos con un punto de vista muy diverso.
- los comentarios: muchas veces alguien en los comentarios agrega situaciones en qeu no sería la mejor respuesta o cosas que se hay que tener en cuenta, eso es muy útil es interesante para mí.
- Snippets! Sí todos los amamos, desde que los inventaron podemos darnos una idea de que hace un código y por qué no funciona en escasos segundos
- etiquetas: tienen referencias a tutoriales y muchas cosas interesantes, el hecho de poder poner etiquetas dentro de las respuestas es algo que en lo personal contribuye a que me pierda mucho más en el sitio al punto de olvidar comer.

Como habrán notado los últimos dos puntos de SOen son trascendentes, y en terminos de negocios, una ventaja injusta, ya que es algo que no podrán suplantar los clones en muchos años.

Algo que no existe y yo sugeriría, sería una especie de popup con enlaces de referencia propuestos por los usuarios y que se pudieran votar. En SOes pasa mucho que la gente quiere compartir links en su intento de ayudar ya que piensan que está mejor explicado en el hiperenlace de lo que ellos lo podrían explicar.

Comment: Thank you for feedback! Could you please add a few links to the personal blogs with translations? Sounds very interesting.