# ¿Los sitios que se "alimentan" de Stack overflow son permitidos?

Tags: discusión, soporte

Buen día, navegando por ahí, me encontré con la siguiente página:

https://stackoverrun.com/

revisando un poco ese sitio, veo que, al momento de hacer alguna pregunta en el sitio, te manda a hacer tu pregunta aquí directamente, lo mismo cuando haces clic en el usuario que pregunto, o quien respondió, y pues me llama bastante la atención que se "alimente" por así decirlo, de tanto SOes como SOen en algunas cosas. 
¿Esto está permitido?

Comment: Relacionada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3795/cual-es-tu-opini%C3%B3n-sobre-sitios-con-contenido-de-stack-overflow-traducidos-auto